# Send properties created in foreach loop to PSCustomObject

Tags: powershell

I want to read out some information of processes running on a webserver. I'm stuck with getting my information into a variable and export it into a log file

How do I get my `$Properties` into the `$ProcessData` PSCustom Object?

Main goal is to get the gdi-handles of every process running on my server.

```
 $sig = @'
        [DllImport("User32.dll")] public static extern int GetGuiResources(IntPtr hProcess, int uiFlags); 
    '@ 
    Add-Type -MemberDefinition $sig -name NativeMethods -namespace Win32
    $processes = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetProcesses()
    [int]$gdiHandleCount = 0
    $ProcessData = New-Object PSCustomObject
    ForEach ($p in $processes)
    {
        try{
            $gdiHandles = [Win32.NativeMethods]::GetGuiResources($p.Handle, 0)
            $gdiHandleCount += $gdiHandles
            $properties = @{
                'ProcessName'=$p.name;
                'CPU'=$p.cpu;
                'Handles'=$p.Handles;
                'GDI-Objects'=$gdiHandles.ToString
            }
        }
        catch {
            #"Error accessing " + $p.Name
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just want to add the GDI objects to the process information. Use a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) for that:

```
$processes = [Diagnostics.Process]::GetProcesses() |
             Select-Object Name, Cpu, Handles, @{n='GDI-Objects';e={
               [Win32.NativeMethods]::GetGuiResources($_.Handle, 0).ToString()
             }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ProcessData = New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{
    'ProcessName'=$p.name;
    'CPU'=$p.cpu;
    'Handles'=$p.Handles;
    'GDI-Objects'=$gdiHandles.ToString
}
```

OR

```
$Properties = @{
    'ProcessName'=$p.name;
    'CPU'=$p.cpu;
    'Handles'=$p.Handles;
    'GDI-Objects'=$gdiHandles.ToString
}
$ProcessData = New-Object PSCustomObject -Property $Properties
```

I typically go with option A

Comment: can not do this, because it's in a foreach loop and would always be rewritten

Comment: @SimonS You could make it work by putting the object creation inside the loop and assigning the loop output to the variable: `$ProcessData = foreach ($p in $processes) { New-Object PSCustomObject ... }`. However, it's much simpler to do this with calculated properties.